# How to capture length of sscanf'd string?

Tags: c++, c, string, parsing, scanf

I'm parsing a string that follows a predictable pattern:

1. 1 character
2. an integer (one or more digits)
3. 1 colon
4. a string, whose length came from #2

For example:

```
s5:stuff
```

I can see easily how to parse this with PCRE or the like, but I'd rather stick to plain string ops for the sake of speed.

I know I'll need to do it in 2 steps because I can't allocate the destination string until I know its length.  My problem is gracefully getting the offset for the *start* of said string.  Some code:

```
unsigned start = 0;
char type = serialized[start++]; // get the type tag
int len = 0;
char* dest = NULL;
char format[20];
//...
switch (type) {
  //...
  case 's':
    // Figure out the length of the target string...
    sscanf(serialized + start, "%d", &len);
    // <code type='graceful'>
    // increment start by the STRING LENGTH of whatever %d was
    // </code>
    // Don't forget to skip over the colon...
    ++start;
    // Build a format string which accounts for length...
    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", len);
    // Finally, grab the target string...
    sscanf(serialized + start, format, string);
    break;
  //...
}
```

That code is roughly taken from what I have (which isn't complete because of the issue at hand) but it should get the point across.  Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach entirely.  **What's the most graceful way to do this?**  The solution can either C or C++ (and I'd actually like to see the competing methods if there are enough responses).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `%n` conversion specifier, which doesn't consume any input - instead, it expects an `int *` parameter, and writes the number of characters consumed from the input into it:

```
int consumed;

sscanf(serialized + start, "%d%n", &len, &consumed);
start += consumed;
```

(But don't forget to check that `sscanf()` returned > 0!)

Comment: @R: Indeed, though I'm lead to believe that it's unspecified whether the `%n` conversion is counted in the return value of `sscanf()` or not, so it's only safe to use it at the end.

Comment: Did you miss this? "Execution of a %n conversion specification shall not increment the assignment count returned at the completion of execution of the function."

Comment: @R: The Linux man page *claims* that the TC contradicts that.  So "unspecified" isn't actually the right term at all.  But there certainly seems to be some confusion about it.

Comment: By the way, a better way to check would be to just pre-assign a negative value to the integer, and then see if it's still negative after `sscanf` returns.

Comment: @R.: Actually it is [TC1 of C90](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc1.htm) that contains the contradictory information, in the §7.9.6.2 example.  So obviously that's superceded if you're using C99, but the situation in C90 does seem a bit murky.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `%n` format specifier to write the number of characters read so far to an integer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++ solution, it could be better, and is hard-coded specifically to deal with your example input, but shouldn't require much modification to get working.

```
std::stringstream ss;

char type;
unsigned length;
char dummy;
std::string value;

ss << "s5:Helloxxxxxxxxxxx";

ss >> type;
ss >> length;
ss >> dummy;
ss.width(length);
ss >> value;

std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

#### Disclaimer:

I'm a noob at C++.

Comment: The extra `x` characters are just there to show that it will not extract them.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use atoi which will ignore the colon.

e.g. len = atoi(serialized + start);

The only thing with atoi is that if it returns zero it could mean either the conversion failed, or that the length was truly zero.  So it's not always the most appropriate function.

Answer (score 0):

if you replace you colon with a space scanf will stop on it and you can get the size malloc the size then run another scanf to get the rest of the string`

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
char foo[20];
char *test;

scanf("%s",foo); //"hello world"
printf("foo = %s\n", foo);//prints hello
//get size
    test = malloc(sizeof(char)* 10);//replace 10 with your string size
    scanf("%s", test);
printf("test = %s\n", test);//prints world

return 0;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the format is overspecified... (using a variable length field to specify the length of a variable length field).

If you're using GCC, I'd suggest

```
if (sscanf(serialized,"%c%d:%as",&type,&len,&dest)<3) return -1;
/* use type, dest; ignore len */
free(dest);
return 0;
```